# What's the difference between dP<0 and dP>0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, pressure, ideal-gas

Assume a situation shown in the image1 below. The column is filled with gas. The number density is denoted as $n$, and the mass of each particle is $m$. Take the axis downward. By considering the force balance, you get

$0 = n m A dhg + A(P + dP) - AP$

$\Rightarrow nmdhg = - dP = -k_B T dn = - \frac{1}{\beta} dn$ (Use $P=n k_B T$. Say $T$ is constant)

$\Rightarrow \frac{dn}{n} = - \beta m g dh$

$\Rightarrow \ln n = - \beta m g h$

$\Rightarrow n = n_0 e^{-\beta m g h}.$

Now, what if the pressure of the top is $P$ and the bottom's one $P+dP$ (as shown in image2)? Then you get

$0 = n m A dhg + AP - A(P+dP)$

$\Rightarrow nmdhg = dP = k_B T dn = \frac{1}{\beta} dn$

$\Rightarrow \frac{dn}{n} = \beta m g dh$

$\Rightarrow \ln n = \beta m g h$

$\Rightarrow n = n_0 e^{\beta m g h}.$

The former result is physically natural. But the latter result is so strange. I believe, the both situation has the difference only of representation, so they are physically the same. However, the results are different.

Could anyone please tell me my mistakes?

---

image1
[image]

image2
[image]

Comment: So I think I agree with your first method, but I don't agree with the steps taken. I think you made two mistakes, but the mistakes canceled giving you a good answer. When you use Newton, you have to add _vectors_. So in the math, we always have to be care about _what is a number_ vs. _what is a variable_. Look at your force vectors. $g$ usually stands for $9.8$. Therefore the first term should be $-nm(dh)Ag$ (that is unless you remember to substitute in a $-9.8$ in your answer. But then you should (at this point) realize the answer is wrong because you have a rising exponential. Second look at

Comment: your force vectors for pressure. Pressure (when used with the ideal gas law) is always measured on an absolute scale (I think). This means $P = P(h)$ is always a positive function. Therefore, to get the directions correct, you should use 
$$ 0 = -nm(dh)Ag -AP(h+dh) + AP(h)$$ which after you factor out a minus sign yields $$ 0 = -nm(dh)Ag -A(P(h+dh) - P(h)) = -nm(dh)Ag - AdP$$

Comment: Then actually, your second method is correct and not the first. Because when you substitute in for $g$ in your second method, the way you did your work, you have to substitute in a $-9.8$ and you'll get an exponential decay

Comment: @DWade64 Thank you. It helps me a lot, truly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that there's an implicit coordinate system missing here. The pressure and the particle-number density $n$ are functions of height (and other variables): $P(h)$ and $n(h)$, so $\mathrm{d}P=\frac{\partial P}{\partial h}\mathrm{d}h= kT\frac{\partial n}{\partial h}\mathrm{d}h$ and $\mathrm{d}n=\frac{\partial n}{\partial h}\mathrm{d}h$.

Now the catch is to choose the direction in which all quantities are positive and to write the integration more properly. You must decide what are the origin and direction of your $h$ coordinate.

Suppose $h=0$ is somewhere underneath the layer and the positive direction is *upwards*. Then the gravitational force is $-mngA\,\mathrm{d}h$ – note the minus sign – the pressure at the bottom is $+AP(h)$ and that at the top $-A[P(h)+\partial P/\partial h\,\mathrm{d}h]$. The difference in sign between the last two expression is because the normals at the two surfaces are opposite. Then we arrive at your second row of equations, and
$$\int_0^h \frac{\partial n/\partial h}{n}\mathrm{d}h = -\beta m g \int_0^h\mathrm{d}h \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\ln\frac{n(h)}{n(0)} = -\beta m g h \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
n(h) = n(0)\,\exp(-\beta m g h).$$
We can find $n(0)$ from the condition
$$n(0)\,\int_0^H \exp(-\beta m g h)\,\mathrm{d}h \equiv N
\quad \Longrightarrow\quad
n(0)=\frac{N\beta m g}{1-\exp(-\beta m g H)}$$
where $N$ is the total number of particles between $h=0$ and $h=H$. We finally find
$$n(h) = N\beta m g \frac{\exp(-\beta m g h)}{1-\exp(-\beta m g H)},$$
which decreases with $h$.

Suppose $h=0$ is somewhere above the layer and the positive direction is *downwards*. Then the gravitational force is $+mngA\,\mathrm{d}h$ – note the plus sign – the pressure at the *bottom* is $-[AP(h)+\partial P/\partial h\,\mathrm{d}h]$, and that at the *top* $+AP(h)$. We obtain your alternative set of equations, and
$$\int_0^h \frac{\partial n/\partial h}{n}\mathrm{d}h = \beta m g \int_0^h\mathrm{d}h \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\ln\frac{n(h)}{n(0)} = \beta m g h \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
n(h) = n(0)\,\exp(\beta m g h).$$
This time $n(0)$ is given by the condition
$$n(0)\,\int_0^H \exp(\beta m g h)\,\mathrm{d}h \equiv N
\quad \Longrightarrow\quad
n(0)=\frac{N\beta m g}{\exp(\beta m g H)-1}$$
which yields a different $n(0)$ than before. Finally,
$$n(h) = N\beta m g \frac{\exp(\beta m g h)}{\exp(\beta m g H)-1},$$
which increases with $h$, as it should be, since in this case we're "moving" toward the bottom.

The "$h$"s in the two cases are related by $h \mapsto H-h$, and if you make this transformation you'll see they are equivalent, as it should be, since they are physically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you. The sentence "The pressure and the particle-number density $n$ are functions of height" was really a large hint to me.

Comment: You're welcome. This calculation really belongs to the domain of continuum mechanics, even if in an elementary way, so it's always good to keep in mind that all quantities have some $(x,y,z,t)$-dependence. Some academic backgrounds (especially theoretical physics, like mine), don't provide a good training in continuum mechanics and replace it with make-do intuitions, which often confuse more than help (as it was in my experience).